# How to check from Apex code if custom setting is protected?

Tags: managed-package, security, customsetting

The question is simple:
Is there any way to figure out from Apex code if custom settings is marked as protected or not? Looking through DescribeSObjectResult cannot find any single method related to that.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by knowing if a custom setting is managed or not?

Comment: @RahulSharma We have some rules which dictate if custom setting should be marked as protected (hidden from subscriber) or not. So based on this we would like to create a test method in our dev org to enforce those rules, i.e. basically control if we accidentally don't forget to make something protected, or cut off access to some settings by mistake.

Comment: Is your custom setting in a managed package?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/protected-custom-settings-in-managed-package-are-not-visible-by-apex-class

Comment: @Ankita Yes, but we are talking about package dev org, i.e. it's the org where we basically are developing this package, so we have access to custom settings - just need to detect in apex code which of them are protected.

Comment: @battery.cord We are talking about use case when we are developing managed package on dev org. It's not when we install it in subscriber org, at that stage, of course, custom settings are not visible at all.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358951/forbid-calls-to-arbitrary-functions-classes-in-external-code

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option here is to use Metadata API or some tools which use MetadataAPI under the hood like Andrew Fawcett package